# Display query results with greatest aggregate value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to build a query that displays the rows with the highest values in the aggregate column, "NumberOfArticles". However, since there are multiple rows with the same highest value, I am unsure how to properly limit the number of rows generated by the query.

```
SELECT WRT_ID, COUNT(ART_ID) AS NumberOfArticles
FROM Articles
GROUP BY WRT_ID
ORDER BY NumberOfArticles DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WRT_ID, COUNT(ART_ID) AS NumberOfArticles
FROM Articles
GROUP BY WRT_ID
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

If there are multiple rows with the highest NumberOfArticles count, the ties will be included.  If you don't want the ties included, but only one of those with the highest NumberOfArticles count, put the GROUP BY in a subquery and change the ORDER BY as needed.

```
SELECT TOP 1 sub.WRT_ID, sub.NumberOfArticles
FROM (
    SELECT WRT_ID, COUNT(ART_ID) AS NumberOfArticles
    FROM Articles
    GROUP BY WRT_ID
    ) AS sub
ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1 DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be enough for you

```
SELECT WRT_ID, max(ART_ID) AS NumberOfArticles
FROM Articles
GROUP BY NumberOfArticles
ORDER BY NumberOfArticles DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want:

```
SELECT A.WRT_ID, (SELECT MAX(B.ART_ID) FROM Articles As B WHERE B.WRT_ID = A.WRT_ID) As NumberOfArticles
FROM Articles A
ORDER BY 2 Desc
```

This uses a sub-select to get the highest Art_Id for each Wrt_Id

I see you have used COUNT in your sample although the question hints more towards max, however if it is the count then you would simply amend to this instead:

```
SELECT A.WRT_ID, (SELECT COUNT(B.ART_ID) FROM Articles As B WHERE B.WRT_ID = A.WRT_ID) As NumberOfArticles
FROM Articles A
ORDER BY 2 Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT WRT_ID, COUNT(ART_ID) AS NumberOfArticles
FROM Articles
GROUP BY WRT_ID
HAVING COUNT(ART_ID)=(SELECT MAX(t.c) FROM ( SELECT WRT_ID,COUNT(ART_ID) AS c 
                                             FROM Articles GROUP BY WRT_ID ) t )
ORDER BY NumberOfArticles DESC
```

This gives you all maximum rows.